# How to configure DMARC when branded email is pulled into Gmail account

Tags: gmail, dmarc

I have a client whose email is hosted on her web host. She has set her Gmail account to download all the email from her web host, and reply using whatever the domain name is in the To field.

I have the DMARC on my own domain set to reject because of the quantity of spam I receive.

All email to me ,sent from her Gmail account, is rejected. I'm assuming it's because her domain name and the source of the Gmail reply are not in sync.

Is there a way that both of us can keep our setup, but that I can receive her replies to my email to her branded address?

Comment: So, to try to see if I understand: You send an email from `Nora@yourdomain.com` to your friends webhost email `friend@webhost.com`. Then, your friend tries to reply from `Nora@yourdomain.com` to `Nora@yourdomain.com`, from her Gmail account? Then, your friend is not playing by the rules. You can't just impersonate an email domain that you don't own, when `DMARC` is configured to `reject` for that domain.

Comment: #Reinto I'm glad you asked for a clarification. In any Gmail account, you can add a setting that 1) will download email from another account you have access to into your email, 2) add the original email address to the To field when you reply. 

This is not claiming to own gmail.com, but it is claiming to own the domain where the email originally landed. Of course, you have to have the credentials to that original email address. Many people use this function to not have to log in to multiple email accounts.

Comment: I'm not completely there yet. I can understand how you would download emails in Gmail and then reply to them. Is she using the email address of her own domain as Sender, when she is replying to you? So first: Nora@yourdomain.com to client@webhost.com and then: client@webhost.com back to Nora@yourdomain.com, but from a Gmail server?

Comment: #Reinto Once the setup is completed in Gmail, to my friend, it feels like she is just receiving and replying to another Gmail. But, behind the scenes, if I sent an email to friend@herdomain.com. 

1. It hits her web host
2. GMail checks her web host, downloads the email and deletes it off the web host.
3. When she replies (in Gmail), Gmail does reply using her Gmail address, but her original branded email.

The problem is that this is similar to how spammers work, but it's a legitimate setup. But, when my own email host receives her reply, it goes balistic and sends her a nasty note.

Comment: Well, I think I understand now. Thank you. The nasty note may shed more light on the exact reason for rejection. Please see my answer for my theory of what is happening.
For future inquiries: The Stack Overflow forum is suited for programming questions. ServerFault.com would be the better place to ask about system configuration and settings.

Comment: Besides the useful answer, it's good to know where to go with this type of question.

Comment: I did check to see if there were other DMARC Questions in StackOverflow, and there seem to be quite a few.

Comment: I agree there are many `DMARC` related questions. But also many of those have not been answered and down voted for being asked in the "wrong" forum. These questions tend to end up in the Information Security forum, the webmasters forum, ServerFault and StackOverflow. Depending on the question, all of those can be the correct forum for the type of question, depending on what exactly is being asked about DMARC. Just some friendly advice.

Comment: That's a very helpful list. I had looked at the Information Security forum, but it says it's for professionals. While I generally fire clients who don't follow my basic security practices, I'm by no means a security professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send an email from `Nora@yourdomain.com` to `Client@WebhostDomain.com` and your client follows the steps in [this article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en), she may be using Gmail's interface, but the email is being relayed by the `SMTP` host configured in Step 1, bullet #7.

If your client didn't add an `SPF` record to her domains that lists that `SMTP` server (step 1, bullet #7) as authorized sending server (or add `DKIM` signing for her domain), then the email might be considered as spoofed email.

The error message your client is receiving may (or may not) support this analysis.

Comment: The part that was missing was indeed the SPF include. In this case, it needed include: _spf.google.com. It needs to be before the ~all and not in a new record.